# How to implement a confirm dialog in WinJS and return the user's choice

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

Using WinJS I'm trying to display a message to the user who has just hit a 'continue' button that they haven't answered the question asked. That displays a dialog (Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog) with two buttons, which allow the user to choose to answer it now (and therefore stay on the uinaswered question) or answer it later (and therefore proceed straight to the next question). In Javascript, I could normally use a confirm dialog, which would halt execution until the user has made a selection and I could then use the returned value to decide whether or not to display the next question. In WinJS, code execution doesn't halt. Here's my function to display the dialog:

```
function doSillyMessage(message, title) {
    var messagedialogpopup = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(message, title);
    // Add commands and set their CommandIds
    messagedialogpopup.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Answer now", null, 1));
    messagedialogpopup.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Answer later", null, 2));

    // Set the command that will be invoked by default
    messagedialogpopup.defaultCommandIndex = 0;

    // Show the message dialog
    messagedialogpopup.showAsync().done(function (command) {
        if (command) {
            if (command.id == 1) {
                console.log('proceed in popup is false');
                proceed = false;
            }
            else if (command.id == 2) {
                console.log('proceed in popup is true');
                proceed = true;
            }

        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that at the point where doSillyMessage is called, the code doesn't wait and so continues with whatever the current value of the 'proceed' variable happens to be. For example, if the value of 'proceed' is false at the point where doSillyMessage is called, it is also false after doSillyMessage is called and is changed to true (if appropriate) only later, when I then see in the console 'proceed in popup is true'. How can I get this stuff to execute in the right order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dialogs are asynchronous; you'll need to wait on a promise in order to delay until the user's dealt with the input.

The easiest thing to do is to return the promise from your call to showAsync. Change this:

```
messagedialogpopup.showAsync().done(function (command) {
```

to

```
return messagedialogpopup.showAsync().then(function (command) {
   if (command) {
        if (command.id == 1) {
            console.log('proceed in popup is false');
            return false;
        }
        else if (command.id == 2) {
            console.log('proceed in popup is true');
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

and change the call to doSillyMessage to:

```
doSillyMessage().then(function (proceed) {
    // proceed will be true or false
});
```

Your callback logic has some holes in it; what do you return if command isn't set, or if it's not 1 or 2?

Comment: Also, to conform to convention, rename the function to `doSillyMessageAsync` to emphasize that it is an async operation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm constantly falling foul of this asynchronous stuff. Your code works like a charm. Thanks also for your comment on the callback logic. I had simply assumed that, as there's nothing else the user can click, command must be set and must be either 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing a dialog helper set to manage my confirmations, alerts etc. This may be useful to you:

**Helper**

```
function confirmAsync(title, msg) {

    // define confirmation buttons
    var buttons = [
        new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Yes"),
        new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("No")];

    // make sure to return the showAsync() promise so we can chain from the call to confirmAsync
    return dialogInterceptor(title, msg, buttons).showAsync();

}


function dialogInterceptor(title, msg, buttons) {

    // create dialog
    var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(msg, title);

    // optionally add buttons
    if (buttons) {

        buttons.forEach(function(button) {

            dialog.commands.append(button);

        });

    }

    // return dialog
    return dialog;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
            confirmAsync("Confirmation title text", "Are you sure you want to do something?")
                .done(function (button) {

                    if (button.label === "Yes") {

                        functionToCallWhenYesIsClicked();
                    }

            });
```

In general though, return promises from your dialogs so that you can do things afterwards. Do be careful from trying to launch a second dialog from a first one, else you'll hit nasty 'Access Denied' messages.